# Sind Nazis zitierfähig?

Tags: discussion

In [dieser Frage mit dem Titel *Meaning of the term "Weißer Jude" ("white Jew") as used by the Nazis on Werner Heisenberg*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/) geht es offensichtlich darum zu verstehen, was die Nazis mit diesem Ausdruck gemeint haben könnten.

David Vogt schreibt [in seinem Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/meaning-of-the-term-wei%c3%9fer-jude-white-jew-as-used-by-the-nazis-on-werner-h#comment172166_71963): *I don't see how this question concerns the German language. The topic seems to be history or racism* und verweist auf history.stackexchange.com.

Meines Erachtens ist dieser Hinweis vollkommen richtig. Allerdings widerspricht der Moderator Jonathan Scholbach mit [seinem Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/meaning-of-the-term-wei%c3%9fer-jude-white-jew-as-used-by-the-nazis-on-werner-h#comment172191_71963): *@DavidVogt This is about racism in the history of the German language, isn't it?*.

Diese Ansicht halte ich für absurd, denn mit diesem Argument lassen sich sämtliche auch gegenwärtige Äußerungen aller möglichen Extremisten als für die deutsche Sprache relevant rechtfertigen. Der tag *etymology* macht das Ganze mehr als deutlich.

In den Antworten wird seitenweise der geistige Auswurf irgend welcher Nazis zitiert. Ich halte das für unerträglich.

Meine Fragen sind deshalb:

1. Sollten wir solche Fragen zulassen? Sollten wir den geistigen Auswurf menschenverachtender Gruppierungen unter dem Deckmantel sprachlich historischer Relevanz hier zur Diskussion stellen?
2. Falls nicht, wie gehen wir damit um?

In meinen Augen gehört diese Frage nicht hier her. Es mag ja sein, dass von Extremisten ersponnene 'Begriffe' sprachliche Relevanz haben, weil sie in der Regel kaum verständlich sind. Es mag ja sein, dass man sie als sprachlich historisch relevant betrachten kann, ... wollen wir uns hier wirklich mit diesem (sprachlichen) Durchfall auseinandersetzen und eine Plattform dafür bieten, dass hier seitenweise menschenverachtender Sprechdurchfall zitiert und auf german.stackexchange.de abrufbar gespeichert wird?

Answer (score 5):

Ich sehe hier zwei verschiedene Fragen, die ich beide für wichtig halte:

1. Sollten wir Fragen zur Sprache und dem Begriffsverständnis der Nationalsozialisten hier zulassen?

und

2. Falls wir  diese Fragen zulassen, wie gehen wir damit am besten um?

## Sollten wir Fragen zur Sprache und dem Begriffsverständnis der Nationalsozialisten hier zulassen?

Die Sprache der Nazis ist Bestandteil der Sprachgeschichte des Gegenwartsdeutsch. Daher ist die Frage hier zunächst einmal on-topic. Das war das, was ich mit dem zitierten Kommentar meinte. Du bezeichnest das als absurdes Argument, aber ich verstehe nicht, warum. Ich habe auch das Gefühl, dass wir ein anderes Verständnis dessen haben, was hier geschieht. Du schreibst:

> Sollten wir den geistigen Auswurf menschenverachtender Gruppierungen unter dem Deckmantel sprachlich historischer Relevanz hier zur Diskussion stellen?

Das sollten wir *nicht*. Das ist hier aber in meinen Augen auch nicht geschehen. Wir stellen hier nicht die Ansichten der Nazis zur Diskussion, sondern wir stellen sie dar. Wir diskutieren hier nicht darüber, ob diese Weltanschauung stimmt. Aber wir stellen dar, wie die Weltanschauung der Nazis ihre Sprache geformt hat.

Es ist unsere Aufgabe, als Community und als Mods, darauf zu achten, dass diese Trennung immer deutlich gemacht wird.

Du schreibst

> mit diesem Argument lassen sich sämtliche auch gegenwärtige Äußerungen aller möglichen Extremisten als für die deutsche Sprache relevant rechtfertigen

> Es mag ja sein, dass von Extremisten ersponnene 'Begriffe' sprachliche Relevanz haben, weil sie in der Regel kaum verständlich sind.

Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen den historischen Nazis und anderen Extremisten. Die Nazis haben leider eine historische Relevanz, die auch Niederschlag in der deutschen Sprache gefunden hat. Der Einfluss des Denkens der Nazis auf die deutsche Sprache ist leider gar nicht so klein. Diese Themen grundsätzlich nicht zu behandeln, würde in meinen Augen das Bewusstsein für die in der deutschen Sprache enthaltenen Spuren der Nazis eher schwächen und und der Vorbeugung rasssistischer, faschistischer und neonazistischer Ideologien in meinen Augen einen Bärendienst erweisen.

Schließlich machst du noch ein weiteres Argument, das ich nicht verstehe. Du schreibst, wir sollten

> [keine] Plattform dafür bieten, dass hier seitenweise menschenverachtender Sprechdurchfall zitiert und auf german.stackexchange.de abrufbar gespeichert wird

Was meinst du genau damit?

## Wie gehen wir damit am besten um?

Ich stimme völlig mit der Antwort von David Vogt darin überein, dass diese Fragen besondere Sensibilität verlangen. Ich selbst habe bei der in Rede stehenden Frage als Moderator folgende Dinge unternommen:

1. Ich habe eine Antwort gelöscht, die nichts zur Frage beitrug, sondern ein Referat über die Geschichte des Antisemitismus war, das erstens off-topic und zweitens durch nichts belegt war.
2. Ich habe die Frage selbst als "protected" markiert, sodass User:innen mit geringer Reputation sie nicht beantworten können. Das hat die Funktion, Troll-Antworten zu unterbinden, und soll auch ein Signal an alle andere User:innen senden.
3. Eine Antwort wies eine mangelnde sprachliche Trennung zwischen Positionen der Nazis und eigenen Positionen auf. Das hätte zu Missverständnissen führen können. Ich habe daraufhingewirkt, diese Trennung deutlicher herauszuarbeiten.
4. Ich habe selbst eine Antwort geschrieben, in der ich mich bemüht habe, die Denkweise und Begriffsgeschichte der Nazis darzustellen, ohne sie zu übernehmen.

Wenn es noch andere Dinge gibt, die wir als Mod-Team tun können, bin ich für Vorschläge offen. Als Community-Mitglied könnt ihr Posts schlechter Qualität downvoten, ihr könnt kommentieren und ihr könnt Flags setzen, um die Mods auf Beiträge aufmerksam zu machen, die eine Intervention auf einem anderen Eskalationslevel erfordern.

Answer (score 2):

#### Was heißt zitierfähig?

Mit zitierfähig bezeichnet man eine Quelle, deren Inhalte man übernehmen will. Etwas ganz anderes sind Inhalte, die man als historischen Beleg, als Exempel zitiert. Derlei Praxis bedeutet nicht, dass man die Texte als zitierfähig adelt.

> In dieser Frage (...) geht es offensichtlich darum zu verstehen, was die Nazis mit diesem Ausdruck gemeint haben *könnten*.

Nein, es geht darum, was sie *gemeint haben*. Aber gut - wenn man keine Belege findet, dann kann man sich auch in Spekulationen ergehen.

> David Vogt schreibt in seinem Kommentar: I don't see how this question concerns the German language. The topic seems to be history or racism und verweist auf history.stackexchange.com.

Das ist eine falsche Dichotomie. Der Begriff ist deutschsprachig, es ist belegt, dass er im Umlauf war. Die Bedeutung (Semantik) ist natürlich Gegenstand der Sprachwissenschaft und politisch aufgeladene Bedeutung ganz besonders. Dass es ein rassistischer Begriff ist exkatapultiert ihn nicht aus der Sprache hinaus. Es kann Geschichte, Politik, Rassismus, Universitätskultur und deutsche Sprache berühren - diese Gebiete schließen sich nicht gegenseitig aus.

Natürlich will man wissen, wer wann den Begriff verwendet hat, ob es ähnliche Bildungen gibt, ob er mit der Hautfarbe zu tun hat usw.

> In den Antworten wird seitenweise der geistige Auswurf irgend welcher Nazis zitiert. Ich halte das für unerträglich.

Du musst Dich dem nicht aussetzen. Andere setzen sich dem aus, um etwas zu lernen, nicht weil sie Genuss beim Lesen empfinden.

> Sollten wir den geistigen Auswurf menschenverachtender Gruppierungen unter dem Deckmantel sprachlich historischer Relevanz hier zur Diskussion stellen?

Du meinst die Autoren benutzen die Frage nur als Deckmantel, um eine Ideologie, die sie insgeheim teilen, bekannt zu machen?

Das kann doch nicht Dein Ernst sein!

> ... wollen wir uns hier wirklich mit diesem (sprachlichen) Durchfall auseinandersetzen und eine Plattform dafür bieten, dass hier seitenweise menschenverachtender Sprechdurchfall ...

Als erwachsene Menschen sollten wir in der Lage sein, ohne zu Kraftausdrücken zu retardieren, von indiskutablen Meinungen zu distanzieren. Dazu gehört auch, dass man nicht spontan desintegriert, nur weil man so etwas mal lesen muss.

Die dt. Geschichte u. die dt. Sprache sind keine Gebiete eitlen Sonnenscheins und fliegender Einhörner und dies ist keine Plattform für 6jährige.

Answer (score 2):

Ich hatte ursprünglich für die Schließung der Frage gestimmt, das aber später zurückgezogen, weil sich der sprachliche Bezug nicht leugnen läßt, egal ob eher formell verstanden (was heißt *weiß* hier? ist das wie *weiße Hochzeit, weiße Weste, weißer Fleck*?) oder begriffsgeschichtlich.

Meine Hoffnung wäre gewesen, daß die Frage auf einem anderen Seite eine bessere Antwort bekommen hätte. Denn die Lieblosigkeit, mit der hier des öfteren verfahren wird und die ich in Grammatikfragen allenfalls ärgerlich finde, wird bei Themen wie Rassismus, Antisemitismus, Nationalsozialismus ziemlich unerträglich.

Die bestbewertete Antwort enthielt ohne jegliche Einordnung den Satz *if you followed Jewish teachings you were called a Jew* – als ob das etwas Alltägliches wäre, was man so stehen lassen kann. Andere erzählen von den Ergebnissen ihrer Google-Suchen. Das ist nicht das Fachwissen, was ich auf dieser Seite zu finden hoffe. Eine inzwischen gelöschte Antwort meinte kundtun zu müssen, daß die Nazis Rassismus nicht erfunden hätten … und weil Google Stack Exchange sehr hoch bewertet, haben Fragen und Antworten auf dieser Seite mitunter eine sehr hohe Sichtbarkeit.

**Meinung:** Zum Nationalsozialismus gibt es viel Sprachliches, was gefragt und beantwortet werden kann, und allein deshalb sollte das Thema auf keinen Fall ausgeschlossen werden. Allerdings sollten die Antworten bei diesem Thema besonderes sorgfältig recherchiert und formuliert werden, am besten von Menschen, die sich mit dem Thema auskennen und nicht "eben mal gegoogelt" haben.

Da es allerdings keinen Mechanismus gibt, diese Sorgfalt zu erzwingen, werden wir wohl mit Fragen und Antworten leben müssen, die für historisch gebildete und feinfühlige Menschen unangenehm zu lesen sind.

Comment: Was mehr zu denken geben sollte ist folgender Eintrag in der timeline für eine zu schließende Frage: "Oct 18 at 10:56 became hot network question". Da sieht man also eine ziemlich suboptimale Frage, eine für die offensichtlich _nicht_ selbst recherchiert wurde, und lauter jump-gun Antworten. Daraus folgt: _'die community'_ hat den ganzen Thread auf die HNQ befördert, statt die Frage zügig als 'too-basic/zero research' zu schließen, oder wenigstens durch edits zu verbessern. _Das_ ist viel bedenklicher. Kaum Sorgfalt/Qualität, doch reichlich upvotes? Dieses Stimmverhalten senkt die Qualität.

Comment: Das Problem mit dem Satz "if you followed Jewish teachings you were called a Jew" ist nicht fehlende Einordnung, sondern eine Ungenauigkeit, die den Punkt der Frage verfehlt. A) Beispielsweise betreffend die Physik, was sollen da "Jewish teachings" sein? Thesen, die ein jüdischer Physiker aufgestellt hat? Als ob die klassische Physik sich vielleicht selbst als jüdisch verstanden hätte. Aber das übersieht, dass es nur sporadisch eine derartige Überlagerung der Abstammung eines Wissenschaftlers mit einer Schule gab. ...

Comment: Der Begriff "weißer Jude" dagegen soll ja gerade jemanden, der nicht Jude war als Juden negativ auszeichnen, weil er unliebsamen Ideen anhängt, darunter Dinge wie Liberalität, Demokratie, Humanismus usw. Es wäre sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass sich heute hier noch wer die Sichtweise, dass das was Heisenberg vertrat eine jüdische Physik war, zu eigen macht aber die Formulierung lässt diese Möglichkeit nicht nur offen, sondern legt sie sogar nahe. Außerdem stört mich die Generalisierung "you were called a Jew" - ja, von Parteigenossen, Agitatoren, sicherlich. ...

Comment: Aber hier klingt es, als sei das täglicher Sprachgebrauch gewesen. Damals war offener Antisemitismus natürlich nichts, was selten war. Ich war auch nicht dabei. Es liegt aber nicht nahe, dass das eine Jedermannfloskel war, unbedacht ausgesprochen wurde.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Du schreibst von "Lieblosigkeit". Mir ist an deiner Antwort nicht klar, ob du das nur allgemein auf german.SE oder (auch) im Besonderen auf diesen Thread beziehst. Kannst du ggf. noch andere Dinge nennen, die an den Antworten lieblos sind? Aber am besten gehört das eigentlich direkt als Kommentar unter die jeweilige Antwort, denke ich.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Führt das nicht etwas zu weit? Lieblosigkeit ist allgemein ein Problem, bei sensiblen Themen besonders. Kommentare sind selbstverständlich das Mittel, mit dem sich Antworten verbessern oder zumindest Schwächen dokumentieren lassen. Aber "hast du das jetzt nur kurz gegoogelt oder hast du dich wirklich mit dem Thema beschäftigt?" erscheint mir als Kommentar zu aggressiv. Ich versuche, fundierte Antworten aufzuwerten, und hoffe, daß solche Antworten andere inspirieren.

Comment: (Der erste Kommentar unter diesem Post hat recht, daß gerade *hot network questions* ein besonderes Problem sind, indem hier der Effekt, daß die erste Antwort die meisten upvotes sammelt, auch wenn spätere Antworten eine höhere Qualität haben. Aber bis diese geschrieben sind, ist die Aufmerksamkeit schon wieder woandershin gewandert.)

Answer (score 2):

### Seit wann ist die Beschäftigung mit Deutschlands düsterster Zeit selbst düster?

Wenn es darum gehen würde, ob die Frage `off-topic` ist, könnte ich die Frage ja noch irgendwie verstehen. Aber:

> In den Antworten wird seitenweise der geistige Auswurf irgend welcher Nazis zitiert. Ich halte das für unerträglich.

Und

> wollen wir uns hier wirklich mit diesem (sprachlichen) Durchfall auseinandersetzen und eine Plattform dafür bieten, dass hier seitenweise menschenverachtender Sprechdurchfall zitiert und auf german.stackexchange.de abrufbar gespeichert wird?

Offensichtlich soll "Nazideutsch" hier keinen Platz haben. Damit bleibt dieser Teil der Geschichte nur leider zuverlässig in genau den falschen Köpfen.

Mal so ein paar Beispiele:

- Hannah Arendts "Eichmann in Jerusalem". Der tiefe Einblick in die Vernichtungsmaschinerie gelingt nur, in dem Zitiert wird und die Denkweise der Nazis rekonstruiert wird. Das ergibt auch "seitenweise menschenverachtenden Sprechdurchfall", aber gerade das bringt die "Banalität des Bösen" zutage
- Die kommentierte Ausgabe von "Mein Kampf". Die ersten Auflagen des Buches waren sofort vergriffen und zwar nicht etwa, weil die Neonazis sich darum rissen, sondern die Historiker/Gedenkstätten/etc. Das Interesse an "Nazisprech", vor allem in aufgearbeiteter Form ist dort nach wie vor groß. Denn: Sachliche Bildungs- und Aufklärungsarbeit lebt auch immer von zeitgenössischen Texten, so wird sie lebendig und so bleibt sie hängen
- Peter Weiss' "Die Ermittlung". Die Angeklagten des Auschwitzprozess werden dort teilweise wörtlich zitiert. Dadurch, dass Weiss ihnen "eine Bühne bietet", macht er die Verbrechen greifbar und hinterlässt eine umso deutlichere Warnung.

Um zu verallgemeinern: "Wer die Geschichte nicht kennt, ist verdammt, sie zu wiederholen". Wie soll das mit dem "Kennen" funktionieren, wenn nicht einmal mehr zitiert werden darf? Gerade im englischsprachigen Raum kursiert mittlerweile so viel Müll über die Nazizeit. Dem setzt man meines Erachtens keine Zitierverbote entgegen, sondern eine sachliche Auseinandersetzung mit dem "Urstoff", dieser ist entlarvend genug.

Answer (score 1):

Hier geht es um deutsche Sprache. *Zitierfähig* ist damit alles, was auch damit zu tun hat. Durch pures Zitieren (sofern das auch passend als Zitat erkennbar gemacht ist und in seinen historischen Kontext gestellt wird) macht man sich noch lange nicht das Gedankengut des Zitierten zu eigen.

> In den Antworten wird seitenweise der geistige Auswurf irgend welcher Nazis zitiert. Ich halte das für unerträglich.

Wie sonst (außer einem Zitat) kann man einem nicht Betroffenen und möglicherweise auch nicht Bewandertem das menschenverachtende Regime klar machen, wie kann man Begrifflichkeiten wie "erbkrank", "Euthanasie", "unwertes Leben", "entartete Kunst", darstellen, mit denen die Nazis gearbeitet haben? Wie soll man einem Deutschlerner klarmachen, dass das an sich vollkommen harmlose Wort "Endlösung" als Euphemismus durch die Nazis so verbrannt ist, dass man es heute nicht mehr in den Mund nehmen kann und darf?

Das einfache Verbannen dieser Begrifflichkeiten macht es sich wesentlich zu einfach. Nix wird dadurch besser, dass man es ignoriert, im Gegenteil.

Ich denke, es ist leicht zu erkennen (und die Moderatoren machen auch einen guten Job darin), wann ein solches Zitat mehr als ein Zitat wird. Hier geht es nicht darum, Nazi-Begrifflichkeiten wieder salonfähig zu machen, sondern genau ums Gegenteil.